# html within php variable

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am building a multi-language site using codeigniter

I have this language file

```
$lang['prot_home_1'] = "Our Crash Protection Plan revolutionizes IT support. Traditional IT support firms only help after disaster strikes, and off the shelf anti-virus software requires maintenance to be effective. Our Crash Protection Plan doesn't react";
```

the problem is if I use `"` to enclose the text, if I where to call on a class, it breaks the string, but if I use `'` to enclose the test, if I get a word like `doesn't`, it breaks the string.

What would be the best way around this issue?

Comment: You need to escape interior quotes with a backslash, if they are the same as the exterior surrounding quotes `"a quoted string that includes a quote: \" inside it"`

Comment: If you "where to call on a class"? Can you please rephrase?

Comment: Also have a read over the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), there's a bit more info about escaping strings there.

Comment: Fantastic! just what I needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the escape character, `\`, to escape your single quotes.

```
$lang['prot_home_1'] = '... Crash Protection Plan doesn\'t react';
```

Comment: Chose this answer because I can break from html, go to php and concatenate my result and then return to html again. It makes links with codeigniter very easy to do!

Answer (score 0):

You could use heredoc if you don't want to escape quotes every single time

```
$lang['prot_home_1'] = <<<HTML
Dear, $username<br/><br/>
Our Crash Protection Plan revolutionizes IT support. 
Traditional IT support firms only help after disaster strikes, 
and off the shelf anti-virus $phpVar software requires maintenance to 
be effective. Our Crash Protection Plan doesn't react.

HTML
;
```

Comment: should I need php within that html string, how would I go about to doing that?

Comment: Due to the nature of codeigniter, and possibly my ignorance, it seems limited php functionality is possible with this method, however, it is very nice for simply large blocks of text.